# Tartar language and UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, linguistics

I'm working on a project that includes transforming latin symbols into the corresponding cyrillic ones. I'm talking about Tartar language which is used by one of many nations in Russia. I tried find these symbols in UTF-8 but failed so far. The only thing I need, is UTF codes for tartar symbols. There are 6 of them.
Thank you!!

Comment: The wikipedia page likely has all the symbols you're looking for, so if you copy the ones you're looking for into your question, we can probably help you encode them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatar_alphabet (Typically the right question is "what is the Unicode name for a given symbol?" From the name, you can find the code point, and UTF-8 is just a specific encoding of code points.)

Comment: If you paste the character into https://www.fileformat.info, it'll generally tell you its name and encodings.

Comment: A [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Why do you care about UTF-8 byte sequences? Nowadays, any (plain text) editor can handle UTF-8 - even Windows Notepad:))

Comment: @JosefZ: User knows about UTF-8. He just asked the block, which it is important e.g. to choose the correct font, or to check support. Plain editors can do UTF-8, but it doesn't mean you know how to type classic English typeset characters (one requires to know the codepoints, and the question is about this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which "6 of them" you are referring to.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatar_alphabet):

> The official Cyrilic version of the Tatar alphabet used in Tatarstan
> contains 39 letters:
>
> А Ә Б В Г Д Е (Ё) Ж Җ З И Й К Л М Н Ң О Ө П Р С Т У Ү Ф Х Һ Ц Ч Ш Щ Ъ
> Ы Ь Э Ю Я

Unicode code points:

```
U+0410 А
U+04D8 Ә
U+0411 Б
U+0412 В
U+0413 Г
U+0414 Д
U+0415 Е
U+0401 Ё
U+0416 Ж
U+0496 Җ
U+0417 З
U+0418 И
U+0419 Й
U+041A К
U+041B Л
U+041C М
U+041D Н
U+04A2 Ң
U+041E О
U+04E8 Ө
U+041F П
U+0420 Р
U+0421 С
U+0422 Т
U+0423 У
U+04AE Ү
U+0424 Ф
U+0425 Х
U+04BA Һ
U+0426 Ц
U+0427 Ч
U+0428 Ш
U+0429 Щ
U+042A Ъ
U+042B Ы
U+042C Ь
U+042D Э
U+042E Ю
U+042F Я
```

Answer (score 0):

Tatar uses Cyrillic script, so you may want to check the following blocks:

- U+0400 ‐ U+04FF (Base)
- U+0500 ‐ U+052F (Supplement)
- U+2DE0 ‐ U+2DFF (Extended A)
- U+A640 ‐ U+A69F (Extended B)
- U+1C80 ‐ U+1C8F (Extended C).

Unicode Common Locale Data Repository (see [tt](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/master/common/main/tt.xml)) has following data:

```
<characters>
    <exemplarCharacters>[а ә б в г д е ё ж җ з и й к л м н ң о ө п р с т у ү ф х һ ц ч ш щ ъ ы ь э ю я]</exemplarCharacters>
    <exemplarCharacters type="auxiliary" draft="contributed">[ғ қ]</exemplarCharacters>
    <exemplarCharacters type="index" draft="contributed">[А Ә Б В Г Д Е Ё Ж Җ З И Й К Л М Н Ң О Ө П Р С Т У Ү Ф Х Һ Ц Ч Ш Щ Ъ Ы Ь Э Ю Я]</exemplarCharacters>
    <exemplarCharacters type="numbers" draft="contributed">↑↑↑</exemplarCharacters>
    <exemplarCharacters type="punctuation" draft="contributed">[\- ‐ ‑ – — , ; \: ! ? . … ' ‘ ’ &quot; “ ” ( ) \[ \] § @ * / \&amp; # ′ ″]</exemplarCharacters>
</characters>
```

As you see, there is not much, and some data is *draft=contributed*, so still draft.